# 'grep -q' not exiting with 'tail -f'

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to implement a script that wait for a specific message in a log file. Once the message is logged then I want to continue the script.

Here's what I am trying out with `tail -f` and `grep -q`:

```
# tail -f logfile | grep -q 'Message to continue'
```

The `grep` never quit and so it waits forever even if 'Message to continue' is logged in the file.

When I run this without `-f` it seems to work fine.

Comment: it might be related to buffering happening in tail. When I run your command it does not exit, but does exit after one more write to the file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`tail -f` will read a file and display lines later added, it will not terminate (unless a signal like `SIGTERM` is sent). `grep` is not the blocking part here, `tail -f` is. `grep` will read from the pipe until it is closed, but it never is because `tail -f` does not quit and keep the pipe open.

---

A solution to your problem would probably be (not tested and very likely to perform badly):

```
tail -f logfile | while read line; do
  echo $line | grep -q 'find me to quit' && break;
done
```

Comment: As a point of detail, the interrupt, quit, and other signals also stop `tail -f`.  Nevertheless, your diagnosis is basically correct.

Comment: @Jonathan: but I'm confused after reading manpage of grep. with `-q` it is supposed to exit immediately after the first match, so the example of the op **should** work. grep quits and stop reading from the pipe

Comment: yes, me too...I'm puzzled about that.  It is a 'new' behaviour to me; I remember `-q` as equivalent to `-s`, and the early termination is surprising.  My best guess is that `grep` is avoiding sending a SIGPIPE to the `tail` by continuing to read, but I've not proved that.  (I was going to edit my comment to remove the second sentence, but I didn't get there in time.)

Comment: Also this doesn't explain why if you write a second line to the file (after the quit message)--even just a "\n"--it will exit as it is supposed to. This implies to me that grep -q will behave in the way the op expects but there is some other weirdness with buffering going on.

Comment: As a point of reference, this command behaves identically to the ops: tail -f xxx|perl -e 'while(<STDIN>){exit if /Stop/}'. Which is to say that it exits correctly only after the second write.

Answer (score 4):

After some experimentation, I believe the problem is in the way that `bash` waits for all the processes in a pipeline to quit, in some shape or form.

With a plain file 'qqq' of some 360 lines of C source (a variety of program concatenated several times over), and using 'grep -q return', then I observe:

1. `tail -n 300 qqq | grep -q return` does exit almost at once.
2. `tail -n 300 -f qqq | grep -q return` does not exit.
3. `tail -n 300 -f qqq | strace -o grep.strace -q return` does not exit until interrupted.  The `grep.strace` file ends with:

   ```
   read(0, "#else\n#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500\n"..., 32768) = 10152
   close(1)                                = 0
   exit_group(0)                           = ?
   ```

   This is one leads me to think that `grep` has exited before the interrupt kills `tail`; if it was waiting for something, there would be an indication that it received a signal.
4. A simple program that simulates what the shell does, but without the waiting, indicates that things terminate.

   ```
   #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <stdarg.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   static void err_error(const char *fmt, ...)
   {
       int errnum = errno;
       va_list args;
       va_start(args, fmt);
       vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
       va_end(args);
       if (errnum != 0)
           fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
       exit(1);
   }

   int main(void)
   {
       int p[2];
       if (pipe(p) != 0)
           err_error("Failed to create pipe\n");
       pid_t pid;
       if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
           err_error("Failed to fork\n");
       else if (pid == 0)
       {
           char *tail[] = { "tail", "-f", "-n", "300", "qqq", 0 };
           dup2(p[1], 1);
           close(p[0]);
           close(p[1]);
           execvp(tail[0], tail);
           err_error("Failed to exec tail command");
       }
       else
       {
           char *grep[] = { "grep", "-q", "return", 0 };
           dup2(p[0], 0);
           close(p[0]);
           close(p[1]);
           execvp(grep[0], grep);
           err_error("Failed to exec grep command");
       }
       err_error("This can't happen!\n");
       return -1;
   }
   ```

   With a fixed size file, `tail -f` isn't going to exit - so the shell (`bash`) seems to hang around.
5. `tail -n 300 -f qqq | grep -q return` hung around, but when I used another terminal to add another 300 lines to the file `qqq`, the command exited.  I interpret this as happening because `grep` had exited, so when `tail` wrote the new data to the pipe, it got a SIGPIPE and exited, and `bash` therefore recognized that all the processes in the pipeline were dead.

I observed the same behaviour with both `ksh` and `bash`.  This suggests it is not a bug but some expected behaviour.  Testing on Linux (RHEL 5) on an x86_64 machine.

Comment: nice analysis! interestingly, `grep -q pattern <(tail -f logfile)` works just fine.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath why is this not an answer yet?

Comment: I think the `tail` process remains alive after grep exits

Answer (score 4):

```
tail -f logfile | grep  --max-count=1  -q 'Message to continue'
```

Admittedly, it exits when the next line is read, not immediately on the matched one.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd post this as an answer since it explains why the command exits after a second write to the file:

```
touch xxx
tail -f xxx | grep -q 'Stop'
ps -ef |grep 'grep -q'
# the grep process is there
echo "Stop" >> xxx
ps -ef|grep 'grep -q'
# the grep process actually DID exit
printf "\n" >> xxx
# the tail process exits, probably because it receives a signal when it 
# tries to write to a closed pipe
```

Comment: Indeed, `tail -f` gets sent a `SIGPIPE` when it tries to write new output to the pipe _after_ the reader on the pipe has exited.  The issue with `tail -f` is that _usually_ the "tail" of a file will fit in a single write to a pipe and even if the reader only reads the first byte and exits, `SIGPIPE` won't be sent until a subsequent write is attempted.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `tail` with the `-f` (follow) option doesn't quit, and continues to provide output to `grep`.  Waiting for lines in a log file would probably be easier with perl/python.

Launch `tail -f` with the Python subprocess module.  Read output from `tail` in a loop until you see the lines you want then exit the Python script.  Put this solution inside your shell script.

The Python script will block the shell script until the desired lines are seen.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the answer to this for my own project. Trying to test when exactly the passed through GPU becomes active on a VMware ESXi VM. Multiple variations of the same question are everywhere. This one is pretty recent. I figured out a way to fool it, and if you can live with your interesting line repeated in the log then:

tail -n 1 -f /var/log/vmkernel.log | grep -m 1 IOMMUIntel >>/var/log/
vmkernel.log

This tails the log, one line at a time, grep checks each line for first occurrence, and appends it to the log then tail quits immediately.

If you like VMware passthough hacking, read more here:
http://hackaday.io/project/1071-the-hydra-multiheaded-virtual-computer