# Using tail in a subshell in conjunction with while/break does not exit the loop

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have been facing a very peculiar issue with shell scripts.

Here is the scenario

Script1 (spawns in background)--> Script2

Script2 has the following code

```
function check_log()
{
    logfile=$1
    tail -5f ${logfile} | while read line
    do
      echo $line
      if echo $line|grep "${triggerword}";then
        echo "Logout completion detected"
        start_leaks_detection
        triggerwordfound=true
        echo "Leaks detection complete"
      fi
      if $triggerwordfound;then
        echo "Trigger word found and processing complete.Exiting"
        break
      fi

    done
        echo "Outside loop"
        exit 0

}

check_log "/tmp/somefile.log" "Logout detected"
```

Now the break in while loop does not help here. I can see "Logout completion detected" as well as "Leaks detection complete" being echoed on the stdout, but not the string "outside loop"

I am assuming this has to do something with `tail -f` creating a subshell. What I want to do is, exit that subshell as well as exit Script2 to get control back to Script1.

Can someone please shed some light on how to do this?

Comment: When you pipe something, you implicitely create a fork (a child) who could not modify environment of parent... Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763942/bash-why-piping-input-to-read-only-works-when-fed-into-while-read-const/13764018#13764018

Comment: wrong link @F -- this is much more related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178888/grep-q-not-exiting-with-tail-f

Comment: @Neeraj you might want to use a `case` statement to compare your trigger word with the input line instead of forking a pipeline of `grep` and `echo` for every input line.

Comment: @GregA.Woods can you please add an answer with an example snippet of using the case statement with tail? (I'm a noob and hence the request)

Comment: Have a look at the edited version of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, although it's not quite the same (it doesn't skip the beginning of the log file at startup):

```
triggerwordfound=
while [ -z "$triggerwordfound" ]; do
    while read line; do
        echo $line
        if echo $line|grep "${triggerword}";then
            echo "Logout completion detected"
            start_leaks_detection
            triggerwordfound=true
            echo "Leaks detection complete"
        fi
    done
done < "$logfile"
echo "Outside loop"
```

The double loop effectively does the same thing as `tail -f`.

Comment: This should work, but it would be better to use a `case` statement rather than forking a pipeline of `echo` and `grep`.

Comment: @GregA.Woods Indeed. My first approach was `if [[ $line =~ $triggerword ]]` but then I remembered he's not using bash, and I went for not modifying his code, on the basis that the double loop part was the most interesting. The rest certainly could be improved.

Comment: Surely you mean either `[ -z "$triggerword" ]` or `test -z "$triggerword"`

Comment: @charles: actually, i think i must have meant `[ -z "$triggerwordfound" ]` but tbh i don't remember anything about my thought processes wrt this question.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of piping into your while loop, use this format instead:

```
while read line
do
   # put loop body here
done < <(tail -5f ${logfile})
```

Comment: Are the double greater-than signs "< <" with a space or are they "<<" (without a space)

Comment: There is a space. `<(command)` is called process substitution and `< <(command)` means redirect the output of process to stdin.

Comment: When I try this I get the following error ./Automation/check_success.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./Automation/check_success.sh: line 20: ` done< <(tail -5f ${logfile})'

I am using shell as this is on macosx and only shell is available.

Comment: This is usually a more confusing form, and it doesn't solve the OP's question.

Comment: @GregA.Woods Yes: If parent process close the unnamed pipe opened by `<()`, then `tail` recieve a `SIGHUP` than close.

Comment: but `<()` is not a portable shell construct and it should be avoided normally

Comment: @GregA.Woods It's not portable to other shells, but most platforms have bash these days. However, you **must** start the script with `#!/bin/bash` (instead of `#!/bin/sh`) or it won't work.

Comment: It still clearly does not solve the OP's problem.  Bash is _not_ universal.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works in a sense, but you won't notice that it does so until another line is written to the file *after* the trigger word has been found.  That's because `tail -5 -f` can usually write all of the last five lines of the file to the pipe in one `write()` call and continue to write new lines all in one call, so it won't be sent a `SIGPIPE` signal until it tries to write to the pipe *after* the `while` loop has exited.

So, if your file grows regularly then there shouldn't be a problem, but if it's more common for your file to stop growing just after the trigger word is written to it, then your watcher script will also hang until any new output is written to the file.

I.e. `SIGPIPE` is not sent immediately when a pipe is closed, even if there's un-read data buffered in it, but only when a subsequent `write()` on the pipe is attempted.

This can be demonstrated very simply.  This command will not exit (provided the tail of the file is less than a pipe-sized buffer) until you either interrupt it manually, or you write one more byte to the file:

```
tail -f some_large_file | read one
```

However if you force tail to make multiple writes to the pipe and make sure the reader exits before the final write, then everything will work as expected:

```
tail -c 1000000 some_large_file | read one
```

Unfortunately it's not always easy to discover the size of a pipe buffer on a given system, nor is it always possible to only start reading the file when there's already more than a pipe buffer's worth of data in the file, and the trigger word is already in the file and at least a pipe buffer's size bytes from the end of the file.

Unfortunately `tail -F` (which is what you should probably use instead of `-f`) doesn't also try writing zero bytes every 5 seconds, or else that would maybe solve your problem in a more efficient manner.

Also, if you're going to stick with using `tail`, then `-1` is probably sufficient, at least for detecting any *future* event.

BTW, here's a slightly improved implementation, still using `tail` since I think that's probably your best option (you could always add a periodic marker line to the log with `cron` or similar (most `syslogd` implementations have a built-in *mark* feature too) to guarantee that your function will return within the period of the marker):

```
check_log ()
{
        tail -1 -F "$1" | while read line; do
                case "$line" in
                *"${2:-SOMETHING_IMPOSSIBLE_THAT_CANNOT_MATCH}"*)
                        echo "Found trigger word"
                        break
                        ;;
                esac
        done
}
```

Replace the `echo` statement with whatever processing you need to do when the trigger phrase is read.

Comment: Of course, it's a *bashism* but bash is portable and work on almost all server environments (where have to work against log files). At all `perl` is generally a better choice for such kind of log file processing.